# React onClick not working despite binding with this...not duplicate

Tags: reactjs

Whats wrong in my code..why is the onclick event handleClick not working.

Its not showing any console log ..I am clicking all over the element

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick() {
         console.log("this Is clicked");
      };

  render(){      
        return (
          <Singleimage onClick={this.handleClick} publicId= {this.props.publicId}>          
         </Singleimage>
      );
  }
}
```

incase you want to see the SingleImage Component

```
import React  , { Component }  from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {CloudinaryContext, Transformation , Image} from 'cloudinary-react';

class Singleimage extends Component {
    render(){      
          return (
            <div>
            <h1>  cloudinary  ,  {this.props.publicId}</h1>

            <CloudinaryContext  cloudName="demo">
                <Image publicId= {this.props.publicId}>
                    <Transformation width="200" crop="scale" angle="10"/>
                </Image>
            </CloudinaryContext>
        </div>
        );
    }
}


Singleimage.propTypes = {
    publicId: PropTypes.string,
  };

  export default Singleimage;
```

Comment: try to return your `Singleimage` component like this `<Singleimage onClick={this.handleClick} publicId= {this.props.publicId} />`

Comment: I did..but still dint work :'(

Comment: can you provide the code of `Singleimage` for more clarity

Comment: yeah sure... let me update the question..but i think since i am not passing the onclick to child component ..it should matter

Comment: Are you sure CloudinaryContext has onClick property?

Comment: the onclick event is on Singleimage  which is basically a html div

Comment: No, the onclick event is on CloudinaryContext.
Try to put the onlick event on the image for instance. Is this working?

Comment: ok ok...actually the onclick event is on both,,,let me remove it from CloudinaryContext

Comment: hope it looks simpler now @ShacharW

Comment: Call `this.props.onClick` from some native element within the `Singleimage` component.

Comment: Now we don't have the Singleimage code, so it is harder to see.
I suggest you to debug it from bottom to top.
Strat from the inner component: Singleimage and see if the click work inside this component, if it does, than hook the callback function to the parent...

Comment: @RickJolly you mean like... <Singleimage onClick={this.props.handleClick} or  withing the Singleimage component ... will <div onClick={this.props.handleClick}

Comment: wait ..let me push the code to github

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using onClick on `Singleimage` use a custom props `handleClickProps`

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick() {
         console.log("this Is clicked");
      };

  render(){      
        return (
          <Singleimage handleClickProps={this.handleClick} publicId= {this.props.publicId} />
      );
  }
}
```

Then in your child component `Singleimage`, onClick call the props `handleClickProps`

```
class Singleimage extends Component {

    clickHandler(event){
        this.props.handleClickProps(event.target)
    }

    render(){      
          return (
            <div onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}  >
            <h1>  cloudinary  ,  {this.props.publicId}</h1>

            <CloudinaryContext cloudName="demo">
                <Image publicId= {this.props.publicId}>
                    <Transformation width="200" crop="scale" angle="10"/>
                </Image>
            </CloudinaryContext>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: sorry it dint work

Comment: try once by placing your onClick on the wrapping `div` instead of `CloudinaryContext ` in `Singleimage` component

Comment: yeah...finally worked :)

Comment: means that...onclick works on native html elements like div , p & span etc...not on custom

Comment: why..did this question even got marked duplicate...there was thing or two to learn from IT :(